# Multiple option of payment on paypal

Tags: paypal

I did a button of 3 options for payment (Buy Now) on PayPal, and when I pasted the code on my website.
Everything looks ok until you click on Buy now, It's transfer to error code on PayPal.
This is the link for the website: http://compx.co.il/?page_id=43

The error code that I get is: 
1.Can not process your request at this time. Return to CompX IT Services and try another option.
2. PayPal can not process this transaction because of a problem on the site of the seller. Contact the seller directly to resolve this issue.

Any suggestion?

Regards,
Dvir

Comment: is it possible to provide this site in English? In my eyes, it will be easier to help for non arabic speakers. It will be just enough to replace the letters.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a character set issue.  The default character set doesn't recognize them so you can fix this problem by changing the text of your option values or by changing the "charset" you're posting to PayPal.

You can follow these steps to modify the character set within your PayPal account:

```
- Log into your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com 
- Click the Profile link 
- Click the 'Language Encoding' link under the Selling Preferences column
- Click the gray 'More Options' button 
- Choose the same encoding you are using for your data off your site
- Select 'Yes' for 'Do you want to use the same encoding for data sent from PayPal to you (e.g., IPN, downloadable logs, emails)?'
- Click 'Save'
```

You can also define the `charset` value in the button code to match the charact values you have set in your options.